# Is there any Difference between forward backward hidden markov model and left-right hidden markov model?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence

> Is there any Difference between forward backward hidden markov model and left-right hidden markov model ?

Answer (score 0):

forward and backward is how you calculate some probabilities of interest using ready to use hmm models and definitions. left to right is correspoding to structure of underlying hidden state of Markov Chain for an HMM. This is because HMM can be viewed as a Markov Chain that also generate observations. so left to right is nothing more than left to right Markov Chain, a MC that only can go to next other state and never come back to previous states again as time propagates.